# How can I update content from the client side in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client, dashboard

So I'm trying to create a dashboard where once authenticated only a main page is initially rendered from rails, then any user interaction after that (like clicking on a nav tab or running a report etc.) will happen on the current page without redirecting to a new page.

I understand that this is most likely done by making AJAX calls to the server, but I feel like its not 'the rails way' to do this since it would include a lot of custom JS to be written. Is there a more 'rails way' I could be doing this, like with partials or some third party framework?

If this is a novice question thats because I am a novice developer. I couldn't find a straight answer to this elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is a server side framework. What you are talking about seems to fall into the family of single page app. For that, custom js will definitely be needed. Rails does not have any major powers on client.

That said, I recommend you take a look into angularjs. It will cut-down your javascript code length by orders of magnitude and is a much better approach to client side javascript. It's readily testable too.

Even if you do choose to stay with jquery, prototype or some other traditional library, you can separate chunks of reusable code regarding ajax and all into various modules and reference them all over. It will reduce mess and help extensibility in long run. (But do take a look at angularjs if not already done so).

Comment: Thanks AA. I have not yet looked at angularjs but I will definitely do so. I am going to wait and see if there are any other suggestions that crop up, but this seems to confirm that I was headed in the correct direction jumping right to JS, rather than overlooking some boilerplate rails functionality.

Comment: Yep. If I may, design all your controllers as an api, rendering json responses and not just html. It will be lot easier later to change code and also put a new front-end on it without changing a single line in your rails code. Plus, it will reduce coupling between your views and backend and also reduce the load on server while making your pages **appear faster**.

Comment: So following your advice if I am sending json responses from the server I should be creating / updateing the actual html client side, rather than forming it serverside and just dropping it in? This seems much more maintainable, but kind of messy if a lot of a given page is determined on the server. I might just be designing this poorly, I'll have to give it another look.

Comment: I'm going to try using PJAX as a bandaid and invest more time into learning angularjs, then implement that